# Help with notation!

Tags: notation

I have calculated the average absolute difference with the accompanying absolute standard deviation. I write this as e.g.:

```
|0.05 +- 0.12|
```

Is this correct?

I have also calculated the average standard deviation for a number of samples. I refer to this as:

```
'µ'
```

Is this also correct? or would sigma be better?

I would appreciate some suggestions on proper notation if these are not good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The confidence interval of an absolute value should be written as

$$|0.05| \pm 0.12$$

because the confidence band (0.12) is absolute in itself, but is described (with $\pm$) as going both ways.

The symbol for average standard deviation is bar-sigma: $\bar{\sigma}$.

Comment: Your notation--which is not standard--would put the lower limit at $-0.07,$ which is not plausible for an absolute value.